# Are AirTags iBeacons?

Tags: airtag, ibeacon

I'm an iOS developer and I need to test some iBeacon detection. I'd like to use an AirTag to be able to test but I did not find if AirTags are iBeacons?

Answer (score 1):

AirTags are separate and not related to iBeacons.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer also specifies, iBeacons and AirTags are two very different things. You cannot use an AirTag as an iBeacon (without taking it apart and reflashing it with different code ofcourse).

However, I would suggest to you that you can use your Mac to simulate an iBeacon, when you haven't got an actual iBeacon to test with. You can do so by installing this program:

https://github.com/lgaches/BeaconEmitter

Or if you prefer a command line tool, you can download this tool using HomeBrew:

https://github.com/watr/mbeacon

For the command line tool, you can use the following command to generate new, random UUIDs:

```
uuidgen
```